# How to prove the number of unlabeled binary trees is the same as the number of BSTs possible

Tags: graph-theory, recursion, trees

How to prove that the number of unlabeled binary trees is the same as the number of Binary Search Tree possible. I know the number of binary search tree is equal to nth catalan number but how would I prove that this is equal to the number of unlabeled binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There are a couple of reasonable approaches.

- You could show that if $T$ is a binary tree with $n$ nodes, there is only one way to label the nodes $1,\ldots,n$ that makes $T$ a binary search tree. This isn’t too hard. Start at the root. If there are $\ell$ nodes in its left subtree, the only possible number to assign to it is $\ell+1$; why?
- You could show directly that there are $C_n$ binary trees on $n$ nodes. This is most easily done by induction on the number of nodes, using the fact that $C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}$, with $C_0=1$.